# (WAMP) Laravel 5.4 - Persistent 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, sql, laravel, driver

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server using Laravel.

I've got two PHP folders in my `wamp64/bin/php` directory, one for version 5.6, and one for version 7.

I downloaded and installed the drivers in the `ext/` folder of both of these directories.

Likewise, I've got two `php.ini` files...and a third one, which I think is a shortcut.

1) `wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/bin/php.ini`
... and the two others exist in the respective PHP folders mentioned above (one for version 5, and one for version 7)

I've pasted the following in all of those:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

However, upon attempting to do anything with the database, Laravel gives me the following error in the logs:

> '**PDOException**' with message 'could not find driver' in *C:\wamp64\www\projects\{project}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68*

I've restarted WAMP several times after making changes, and I'm not sure why the application won't communicate with the database.

I've also checked the `.env` as well as the `default` value in `database.php`

I don't know what's going on, and I am looking for some guidance in this issue.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all from wamp icon you need to select the version of php,
then go to that php.ini
and the remove the ; from the 2 lines you posted,
there is no need of adding another php.ini 
after removing ; restart your wap server

hope it helps

Comment: There is no `;` in the two lines that I posted... I didn't add another php.ini, I don't think you understood my question but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was quite confusing, and honestly there doesn't seem to be nearly enough information on this. Videos, articles, blog posts etc. I didn't find anything accurate.

Anyway this is what worked for me, and I'll probably make a start-to-end tut on YouTube...

This assumes that you're oke with using PHP7

1) Download WAMP32-Bit, **important:** run the installation as administrator.
 
2) Download the [PHP SQL Driver](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV40.EXE) (4.0) (or an other version if you don't want to use PHP 7)
3) Extract the drivers into `/wamp/bin/php/7.x.xx/ext/` directory
4) Using the wamp aestan tray menu, open `php.ini` - add the following two lines:

> extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
>   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll

I understand that some extensions rely on others, and thus they need to be placed in specific orders, for that reason I should mention that I pasted these two right below the following extension:

> ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

which, as you see, is commented out.

Next, restart wamp and you should hopefully be all set. On `http://localhost` where you see the list of extensions, you should see `sqlsrv` somewhere in there.

Hope this helps someone.